# Can't access row with 'fieldName' using MAX() in PHP MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, max

I have small PHP script which has

```
$query  = "SELECT MAX(id) FROM `dbs`";
//query run 
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$val = $row[0];
```

Which runs fine, but I want to understand why i can't access the row with the fieldname, like if i have this

```
$query  = "SELECT id FROM `dbs`";
```

i am able to use the folowing

```
$val = $row['id'];
```

but whenever i use this MAX() function, i have to change to

```
$val = $row[0];
```

to access the values

I have no clue about this. Any help would be appreciated. Thankss

Comment: Use a column alias `$query  = "SELECT MAX(id) AS maxid FROM `dbs`";`  And get `$row['maxid']`

Comment: ok that worked, but why with max()

Comment: You could also have done `$row['MAX(id)']` but that's more difficult.  If you want a simple column name, you need to use an alias. Same thing if you did a calculation like `SELECT (val1 + val2) FROM tbl`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to give it an alias:

```
<?php
$query  = "SELECT MAX(id) AS `id` FROM `dbs`";
//query run 
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$val = $row['id'];
```

Edit:

To explain this it's probably best to show an example of a different query:

```
SELECT MAX(`id`) AS `maxId`, `id` FROM `dbs`
```

Using the above it will return as many rows are in the table, with 2 columns - `id` and `maxId` (although `maxId` will be the same in each row due to the nature of the function).
Without giving it an alias MYSQL doesn't know what to call it, so it won't have an associative name given to it when you return the results.

Hope that helps to explain it.

Comment: Can you please explain, why this only in MAX()?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT MAX(id) AS myFieldNameForMaxValue 
  FROM `dbs`
```

and then

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$val = $row['myFieldNameForMaxValue'];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you run this query on mysql commandline you'll see that the field name returned by mysql is MAX(id). Try running on phpmyadmin and you'll see the same. So if you try $row['MAX(id)'] it'll work. When using a mysql function, it gets added to the name, so use an alias, like other said here, and you're good to go: SELECT MAX(id) AS `id` FROM `dbs`. Also, never forget to use the `` ` chars, just in case you have some columns/tables with reserved names, like ``from`.